# Nuxt3 : [nuxt] [request error] [unhandled] [500] fetch failed (http://localhost:3000/__nuxt_vite_node__/manifest)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt3

What does this error mean?
[image]

I have done no changes to my Code. When I build my app it works but on dev, it show me this error: `npm run dev`

I tried to rebuild the app, deleted all node_modules, and installed and updated the dependencies.

here is the stracktrace:

```
at async $fetchRaw2 (/D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/node_modules/ofetch/dist/shared/ofetch.502a4799.mjs:180:24)
at async /D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:745:20
at async /D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:826:64
at async /D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:378:22
at async Object.handler (/D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1196:19)
at async toNodeHandle (/D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1271:7)
at async Object.ufetch [as localFetch] (/D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/node_modules/unenv/runtime/fetch/index.mjs:9:17)
at async Object.errorhandler [as onError] (/D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:462:30)
at async Server.toNodeHandle (/D:/IAICB-70/inteliaiclipboard/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:1278:9)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

using node v18 you should update your dev script in `package.json` file like below :

```json
"dev": "nuxt dev --host 0.0.0.0"
```

If the issue still occures :

```json
"dev": "nuxt dev --host 0.0.0.0 --https --ssl-cert localhost.pem --ssl-key localhost-key.pem"
```

If you are using docker add this line to your docker file :

```js
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0
```

It is likely an SSL issue or something with node v18
This was working fine with v16

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working.
I used this page on [storyblok](https://www.storyblok.com/faq/setup-dev-server-https-windows)

This is what I have in scripts:

```
"proxy": "mkcert -install && mkcert localhost && local-ssl-proxy --source 3010 --target 3000 --cert localhost.pem --key localhost-key.pem",
"dev": "nuxt dev",
```

I ran the proxy first with `npm run proxy` and ran a second terminal where I ran

```
npm run dev
```

My project was served on https://localhost:3010/

Comment: What is "local-ssl-proxy"? Its does not work for me

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was adding `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0` to my env., see https://nuxt.com/docs/api/commands/dev#nuxi-dev

E.g., adjusting the `"dev"` script in the `package.json` to
`"dev": "NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 nuxt dev",`